# Mysql php private email like messaging system

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, messaging

I'm building a small messaging system for my app, the primary idea is to have 2 tables.
Table1 messages

```
Id,sender_id,title,body,file,parent_id
```

Here is where messages are stored, decoupled from whom will receive it to allow for multiple recipients.

Parent I'd link to parent message if its a reply, and file is a blob to store single file attached to message

Table 2 message_users

```
Id,thread_id,user_id,is_read,stared,deleted
```

Link parent thread to target users,

Now for a single user to get count of unread messages I can do

```
Select count(*) from message_users where user_id = 1 and is_read is null
```

To get count of all messages in his inbox I can do

```
Select count(*) from message_users where user_id = 1;
```

Question is how to combine both in single optimized query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're trying to achieve something that will total rows that meet one condition and the total rows that meet an extra condition:

```
|---------|---------|
| total   | unread  |
|---------|---------|
| 20      | 12      |
|---------|---------|
```

As such will need something with a form along the lines of:

```
SELECT A total, B unread FROM message_users WHERE user_id=1
```

`A` is fairly straightforward, you already more-or-less have it: `COUNT(Id)`.

`B` is marginally more complicated and might take the form `SUM( IF(is_read IS NULL,1,0) )` -- add 1 each time is_read is not null; the condition will depend on your database specifics.

Or `B` might look like: `COUNT(CASE WHEN is_read IS NULL THEN 1 END) unread` -- this is saying 'when is_read is null, count another 1'; the condition will depend on your database specifics.

In total:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) total, COUNT(CASE WHEN is_read IS NULL THEN 1 END) unread FROM message_users WHERE user_id=1
```

Or:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) total, SUM( IF(is_read IS NULL,1,0) ) unread FROM message_users WHERE user_id=1
```

In terms of optimised, I'm not aware of a query that can necessarily go quicker than this. (Would love to know of it if it does exist!) There may be ways to speed things up if you have a problem with performance:

- Examine your indexes: use the built in tools `EXPLAIN` and some reading around etc.
- Use caches and/or pre-compute the value and store it elsewhere -- e.g. have a field `unread_messages` against `user` and grab this value directly. Obviously there will need to be some on-write invalidation, or indeed some service running to keep these values up to date. There are many ways of achieving this, tools in MySQL, hand roll your own etc etc.
- In short, start optimising from a requirement and some real data. (*My query takes 0.8s, I need the results in 0.1s and they need to be consistent 100% of the time -- how can I achieve this?*) Then you can tweak and experiment with the SQL, hardware that the server runs on (maybe?), caching/pre-calculate at different points etc.

Comment: There is no need for the case inside the count statement. COUNT already only counts non-null values. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, when you count a field, it only counts non null occurrences of that field, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id), COUNT(user_id) - COUNT(is_read) AS unread
    FROM message_users 
    WHERE user_id = 1;
```

Untested, but it should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sum with `CASE WHEN` clause. If `is_read` is null then `+1` is added to the sum, else `+0`.

```
SELECT count(*),
  SUM(CASE WHEN is_read IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_unread
  FROM message_users WHERE user_id = 1;
```